# Finding the volume bounded to the area of $z = x + y+ 2, z=0$ and cylinder $x^2 + y^2 = 16$

Tags: integration

I want to find the volume bounded to the area of $z = x  + y+ 2, z=0$ and cylinder $x^2 + y^2 = 16$ with triple Integral.

I appreciate someone to give me the approach or a hint on what to do?

Thank you.

Comment: You have volume bound, below $z-$axis and above. Is it $z = 0$ or $z \geq 0$?

Comment: z = 0 @MathLover

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, the plane $z = x + y + 2$ cuts the cylinder below and above $XY$ plane. So you have volume bound between the plane, cylinder and plane $z = 0$ both above $XY$ plane and below. So if you are doing by hand and not an online calculator, it is a bit tricky to get the right bounds and a workable integral without change of variable.

So the approach I suggest is to rotate the plane by $\frac{\pi}{4}$ such that it is parallel to $y-$axis. So use the below change of variable,

$u = \frac{x + y}{\sqrt2}, v = \frac{x - y}{\sqrt2} \,$ $\big($or in cylindrical coordinates, $u = r \cos (\theta - \frac{\pi}{4}), v = r \sin (\theta - \frac{\pi}{4})\big)$

So the plane $z = x + y +2 \,$ will become $z = u \sqrt2 + 2$

The equation of the cylinder will be $u^2 + v^2 = 16$ (as it is rotation, it would remain the same. If you plug in $x, y$ in terms of $u, v$ in $x^2 + y^2 = 16$, you can check).

Now you need to find the volume of cylinder $u^2 + v^2 = 16$ between planes $z = u\sqrt2 + 2$ and $z = 0$.

This is a lot more workable in both cartesian as well as cylindrical coordinates.

By the way if you use online calculator, using absolute function or min, max function gives you the volume easily. The above approach is when you have to do it by hand.

Comment: Thanks I appreciate your help dude

Comment: You are welcome! Feel free to reach out if you get stuck.

Answer (score 2):

Note that the average height at the center of the cylindrical shape is $h=2$, which leads its volume $V=\pi r^2 h= 32\pi$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$V=4\int^4_0dx\int^{\sqrt {16-x^2}}_0dy\int^{x+y+2}_0dz$$

More explanation:

Let's start with simple form We want to find volume of a cylinder bounded by $x^2+y^2=16$, $z=0$ and $z=a$.We find a quarter of volume and multiply it by 4. The upper bound of x is 4, y is $y= \sqrt {16-x^2}$ and z is a and we can write:

$$V=4\int^4_0dx\int^{\sqrt {16-x^2}}_0dy\int^a_0dz$$

Now if a is a function of x and y it would mean the upper bound of z is a function of x and y(as mentioned in question).For y we considered $y=\sqrt{16-x^2}$ which is a circle, similarly we put $z=x+y+2$ , which is a plane,as the upper bound of z.If a is constant the integration will be easy, if it is a function of x and y , then integration becomes a bit complicated and messy, that's why other answers to this question suggest simpler method with easier calculations.

Comment: Thanks dude, I appreciate it

Comment: @PNDas, which part is not clear for you; bounds?

Comment: @PNDas, see edit in answer.

Comment: So you are calculating signed volume(i.e. both above xy-plane and below xy-plane)?

Comment: You may think so. the volume is between z=0 and z=x+y+2, if x and y are such that z=x+y+2<0 then it is under xy plane.